# Look for name in column and get their index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several names. I want to look for the name on the pair_stock column and get the index value of that name.

[image]

So if i do :

```
df['pair_stock'].get_loc("MMM-MO")
```

I want to get a 0

So if i do :

```
df['pair_stock'].get_loc("WU-ZBH")
```

But it shows these error

i want to get 5539

But it shows these error:

[image]

Comment: `get_loc` is a method of `pd.index` not `pd.Series`

Comment: Not supposed to post pictures in posts.

Comment: so how can is solve it ?

Comment: i put pictures and code so i can explain my issue better

Comment: @TiagoEmanuelPratas just do `df[df['pair_stock'].eq("MMM-MO")].index`

Comment: Make `pair_stock` the index or filter the dataframe columns normally without `get_loc` like @It_is_Chris suggests

Comment: Another way is `df[df['pair_stock'].isin(['MMM-MO'])].index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get_loc` gives you the integer index for an index.

`'pair_stock'` isn't the index.

One option you have is to make it the index, which I think is actually what you want.

Another option (to get the index value for a row with that label) is akin to this:

```py
df.loc[df['pair_stock']=="MMM-MO"].index.values
```

That gives you an array. You can grab just the first item, but if you know it's unique, maybe it should just be your index.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`df.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html#pandas.DataFrame.index).

For example, to get all the indices that has the `'pair_stock'` name of `'MMM-MO'`:

```
df.index[df['pair_stock'] == 'MMM-MO'].tolist()
```